# How to Index multiple items of array with intervals in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose that I have a list:

```
import numpy as np
a = [2, 4, 6, 8, ..., 1000] # total 500 elements
b = np.array(a)             # numpy version
```

I want to get *1st to 100th, 201st to 300th, 401st to 500th* elements and make them into a new array.

To this end, I've tried the following codes:

```
a_sub = a[0:100] + a[200:300] + a[400:500]
b_sub = np.concatenate((b[0:100], b[200:300], b[400:500]))
```

But I want to do it with a simple oneline-indexing

Say:

```
a_sub = a[(0:100, 200:300, 400:500)]
a_sub = a[[0:100, 200:300, 400:500]]
b_sub = b[[0:100, 200:300, 400:500]]
b_sub = b[[0:100, 200:300, 400:500]]
```

But the above are all invalid and I couldn't find such a oneliner indexing.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible . Or do you want this `a_sub = b[range(0,100)+range(200,300)+range(400,500)]`

Comment: I mean you can't index a list like that in a line specifically `a_sub = a[(0:100, 200:300, 400:500)]`

Comment: Did any of the solutions posted here work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You could use reshaping with [`np.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) and [`slicing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), like so -

```
np.array(a).reshape(-1,100)[::2].ravel()
```

If `a` is a NumPy array, you could do like so -

```
a.reshape(-1,100)[::2].ravel()
```

Comment: Note that this solution only works for interval of constant size and spacing (one interval of size 100 every 100 items) as in the OP's example.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the slices to a mask-array (by slicing an ones-array), and union the mask-arrays using the `|` (or) operator.

```
ones = np.ones(b.shape, dtype = bool)
mask = ones[ 0:100] | ones[200:300] | ones[400:500]
b_sub = b[mask]
```

Note that if your slices overlap, or appear in a non-increasing order, this results with a different array than your original code (items will not repeat, and will always appear in the same order as in the original array).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`np.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
a = range(2, 1002, 2)
edges = [100, 200, 300, 400]
subarrays = np.split(a, edges)
b = np.hstack(subarrays[i] for i in [0, 2, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

well, it is pure python, but maybe it may solve your question

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8, ..., 1000]
slices = ((0, 100), (200, 300), (400, 500))

def new_from_slices(list_, slices):
    return list(itertools.chain(*[list_[s[0]:s[1]] for s in slices]))
new_from_slices(a, slices)
```

Answer (score 0):

two others one-liner :

```
[x for i,x in enumerate(a) if i//100%2==0] #python
b[np.arange(len(b))//100%2==0] # numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

or using hstack (+ adds the values element wise)

```
a = np.arange(1000)
limits = [(0, 100), (200, 300), (400, 500)]
b = np.hstack(a[low:high] for low, high in limits)
```